# SOLR: facet.field is working for each word in a field differently, how to apply facet.field for whole field sentence?

Tags: solr

In facet.field, I have added "MerchantName" field, so I got result as below

```
"facet_fields":{
    "MerchantName":[
        "amazon",133281,
        "factory",99566,
        "club",99566,
        "fashion",4905,
        "swish",4905,
        "store",1001,
        "swank",1001,
        "the",1001
    ]
}
```

In the above array, "club factory", "swish fashion" and "the swank store" are in a single field, but an array as you can see these are treated as a different word.

So how to apply facet query on the whole field which returns an array with whole field value?

Comment: whats the fieldType applied on MerchantName field. Try by having string as field type to the same.

Comment: current field type is text_general, so trying with field type string now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `MerchantName` used for faceting. This field should be defined in `schema.xml` as a string `(type="string")` in order for the facet to use the whole text.

As you are using a text based field with field type as `text_general`, the value will be split into multiple tokens. The same is the case with `MerchantName` field.

Otherwise it will divide it according to the way it has been tokenized.

You can also add `docValues="true"` for a field `MerchantName`, then DocValues will automatically be used any time the field is used for sorting, faceting or function queries.

For faceting Solr could get use of `DocValues` - which is special way of recording field values internally that is more efficient for some purposes, such as sorting and faceting, than traditional indexing.

Comment: trying with string field type